# How do I cache a find in a controller using memcache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I have this method in a controller:

```
def article_info
  if @article = Article.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    @title = @article.title
    @description = @article.excerpt
    @body = @article.body
  else
    render_404
  end
end
```

I ultimately want to cache the results of `Article.find_by_permalink` so that query isn't executed every time an article is accessed.

So, how do I go about caching that query? Can I be cached from within the controller?

CLARIFICATION: I'm looking to cache this for an indefinite amount of time (until I decide to expire it). I'll ultimately be using memcache to do this.

Comment: Won't that do it? whenever you use @article, there won't be any query run, it will just use your @article ActiveRecord object

Comment: Added clarification to my post. I'm looking to cache this for an indefinite amount of time (until I decide to expire it). I'll ultimately be using memcache to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a new method in your model as described [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1):

```
# models/article.rb
def self.all_cached
  Rails.cache.fetch('Article.all') { all }
end
```

Then your calls to `Article.all_cached` would not query the database if the result is cached. Otherwise it would fetch the result from the database.

**Update:** Your `find_by_permalink` call could be replaced with `cached_find_by_permalink`:

```
# models/article.rb
def self.cached_find_by_permalink(permalink)
  Rails.cache.fetch('Article.find_by_permalink.' + permalink) do
    find_by_permalink(permalink)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the log? Usually rails is pretty good at caching things by itself.

A cache database call is noted as such:

```
**CACHE (0.0ms)**   SELECT * FROM `funnels` WHERE bla bla
```

If it doesn't satisfy you, try looking at [this tutorial on rails envy](http://railsenvy.com/2007/2/28/rails-caching-tutorial).

Of course if you do ...

```
@article = Article.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
@title = @article.title
@description = @article.excerpt
@body = @article.body
```

... only 1 database query is made. Calling @article will not reload the object.

Comment: Added clarification to my post. I'm looking to cache this for an indefinite amount of time (until I decide to expire it). I'll ultimately be using memcache to do this.

Comment: Checkout the tutorial I put in my answer, it seems to me that it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

This was covered in [Railscasts episode 115: Caching in Rails 2.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1).

Answer (score 0):

You don't cache model objects in the controller, you cache them in the model.